# USB 3.0 Controller ports on motherboard not responding

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, windows-10, usb-3

After installing Windows 10 I noticed that my 4 USB 3.0 ports on my ASUS MAXIMUS VI FORMULA motherboard have stopped working. After looking in the Device Manager i seen a USB Controller with an "**Configuration Descriptor Request Failed**" error. I tried Uninstalling & Updating the driver, turning off USB power saving, and Reinstalling the Intel Chipset without much luck.

I dug a bit deeper to try and find a way to see what the system was doing when it was trying to enable the device as the Event Viewer wasn't showing anything. I managed to get a **[usbtrace.etl](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gz55nrooxby3jbc/usbtrace.etl?dl=0)**<-FILE) file by Capturing USB event traces from a site i found. I then had to download a program called **[Microsoft Message Analyzer (MMA)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/archive/2013/11/09/capturing-usb-etw-traces-with-microsoft-message-analyzer-mma.aspx)** to view the file but was unable to understand most of it.

I don't know if there are any Tech Wizards out there who can understand this debug program to tell me if i have a faulty USB 3.0 Hub or if its something else. I'l link the file and if anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

I'm thinking that the Hub is malfunctioning as i have been unable to find a solution by using google. So i wanted to ask here before talking to the knuckle heads at ASUS Support about a Fix/Warranty Replacement.

*Apologies if the formatting is not right.*

Comment: I don't need to look at the file to tell you the hub is malfunctioning given that Windows 10 has built-in support for USB 3.0 so it does not require drivers for the hub to work.  *So if the devices connected to the HUB are not even being detected then you have experienced a hardware failure not a software failure.*

Comment: Ah i was afraid of that... thx